# Why would this be throwing a Exception message: Redirect URI cannot contain newline characters.?

Tags: vb.net, iis

Have some VB.NET code that's looks like this:

```
If (strSPToken <> "ERROR") AndAlso (strSPToken <> "EMPTY") OrElse (strSPToken <> "") Then
                Page.Response.Clear()
                Page.Response.Redirect(String.Format("https://www.somewebsite.com/authenticationsso.ashx?strToken={0}&strEmail{1}", strSPToken, strEmail))
                                Else 
               Page.Response.Redirect(strRequestUrl)
            End If
```

Basically what this does is a users email is passed to the 3rd party site and a token is generated and returned. Then in turn both are passed together with this redirect to log the user in. I have a few others similar to this and they work fine but somehow I keep getting the Newline error in IIS. The only thing that's different from my other authenticators is that this end point URL is .ashx. My others are .asmx or REST.

I've tried the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(URL)` option but still doesn't work...

Thoughts?

Comment: Work from the assumption that the exception message is accurate.  The trouble with newlines in a string is that you can't see them in the debugger.  You could type "strSPToken.ToCharArray()" in the debugger expression to see the individual characters.  Repeat for strEmail.

Comment: The immediate window dump will render the newlines. If you don't have an immedite window, open the command window and type `immed` then pause with a breakpoint and type `? strSPToken` to dump the value to the window.  - Edit Oh the text visualizer will also render newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `strSPToken` is, it has a newline in it, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

I suppose it's also possible the email address has a new line in it, or `strRequestUrl`.

Use your debugger.